# Polynomial division over fields

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field, $f,g \in K[x]$ with $\deg(f)=n,\deg(g)=m$.

(1) How can I show that polynomial division with remainder can be performed with at most $(2m+1)(n-m+1)+1$ field operations?

(2) What is the maximum number of operations when we assume that $f$ and $g$ are monic?

I really have no clue where to start here ...

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i, g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m d_ix^i$

1. Invert the leading coefficient of $g(x)$, i.e. compute $d_m^{-1}$, which takes +1 field operation.
2. Compute $d_m^{-1}c_n$, which takes +1 field operation.
3. For each $i=m-1, m-2, \cdots 0$, compute $(d_m^{-1}c_n)d_{i}$ then $c_{i+n-m}-(d_m^{-1}c_n)d_{i}$, which takes $2m$ field operations.
4. Repeat 2-3, until the result has degree $<m$, which repeats no more than $n-m+1$ times.

Put all together, it takes no more than $1+(1+2m)(n-m+1)$ field opertions.

To solve (2), note that we don't have to compute $d_m^{-1}=1$ at all. $f$ is monic helps only once, as $f-x^{n-m}g$ is not necessarily monic any more. These should be enough to help get the result from the above steps.